# VSCode very slowly when debug C++ if using pretty-printer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gdb, pretty-print

when I set pretty-printer in ~/.gdbinit as follower.

```
python
import sys 
sys.path.insert(0, '/usr/share/gcc-4.8.2/python')
from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
register_libstdcxx_printers (None)
end
```

the vscode is lag,this is a picture to show that:
[Is it calculating the variables?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1hTt.png)

when I delete pretty-printer settings in ~/.gdbinit,the project debug normally.